# Ubuntu 13.04 and Garmin 405 Ant+

Tags: 13.04, usb

How do I get ubuntu 13.04 to recognise the Garmin 405 ant+ usb device so I can download data from the Garmin 405 to python trainer or Garmin connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You can install the Garmin Ant Downloader, using Synaptic,  if you don't have synaptic installed, you can do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, you can open the application by searching in dash for it, once open, search for garmin, and one the search is done install the garmin-ant-downloader.

[image]

Right click on it, and choose Mark for Installation

[image]

Click on Apply to start the installation

[image]